# Please reopen this question about finding non-existent relationships between two tables

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49312832/1061426) has been marked by someone as a duplicate.I'm not sure why they think it's duplicate, the answer in the suggested question does not apply (actually, I went out of my way to avoid the dupe tag noting "three tables", but oh well).

Can someone who knows about sql in general, and sqlite in particular please weigh in on if

- this is really a duplicate
- if it is a duplicate, what the code would be anyway, because I cannot work it out from the dup'd question

thanks

Comment: I'm naively thinking two left joins - one to your join table and another to your orders table - is why they'd close that as a dupe...

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe but you can also put some more effort into the question(clear schema with data in question, description of what you tried, link to http://sqlfiddle.com/ with the schema and the query you tried) Shog9 really shouldn't be doing this for you.

Comment: @Makoto you'd think, right? I was hoping the outer would do the trick, but it doesn't at all

Comment: @Oleg I just assumed that, with everyone and their mother using Android, this was something that had been done to death, and i couldn't find it. I am expecting a dupe tag, but to one that covers the problem

Comment: One of the big advantages of SQLite is that it's not all that special; you can often adapt techniques from other database engines pretty easily. OTOH... This is kinda hard to search for. The closest duplicate I found in a short search was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544094/mysql-finding-rows-that-dont-take-part-in-a-relationship), and it's still significantly different.

Comment: For future reference, you can @username ping the user who closed your question, if you'd like to ask them to clarify their reasoning.

Comment: Wait... So you believe it's a duplicate, but you ask it anyway so we can find it for you? Or am I missing something....

Comment: @MikeM. &@bharal *"For future reference, you can @username* *ping the user who closed your question"* - Just to clarify, you can only ping a closer if it's a gold badge user. That would always only be the last closer. Of course if there's only one closer, then that closer must be a gold badge user.

Comment: @robinCTS Yes, I was aware, but that point might not have been clear from my comment. Thank you for clarifying that for the OP.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry. Figured you knew. Was just clarifying and making you aware it might not have been clear to the OP. Should have been clearer myself ;-) Should have had the @'s swapped around.

Comment: @Patrice You *are* missing something ;-) - *"and i couldn't find it"*. bharal looked for a duplicate, expecting to find one, but when one wasn't found, went ahead and posted the question, fully expecting another user to find the duplicate and close the question. Unfortunately, it *was* closed, but with an incorrect duplicate target!

Comment: @robinCTS No worries. For the longest time, I did think everyone in a close banner was pingable, and even told a couple users as much. Had to do a SEDE search on my comments, and post a few corrections. Whoops.

Comment: @MikeM. Lol. The one or two mistakes I've made have been one-offs, and I realised not too long afterwards. They were easy to correct, with no fancy SEDE search required ;-) PS I presume you are also now aware that any user that has edited a post is also ping-able  even though their names don't autocomplete?

Comment: @robinCTS  Yeah, I learned that one early on, when I saw someone ping an absent user, and they came outta nowhere to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the closer misread your question. If I'm reading it correctly, it's a *bit* more involved than just matching up rows from one table that don't have a corresponding row in another.

It might still be a duplicate, but not of the question it was closed as a duplicate of.

I've edited your question to clarify what I perceived as your intent, and reopened it.

Comment: thankyou very much, yes, I am expecting it to be closed, or rather, if he surprised if nobody had asked this